# Should Dispose be called when rethrowing an unhandled exception?

Tags: c#, dispose

Supposed I have a class like the below:

```
public class DisposableClass : IDisposable()
{
   private readonly Timer timer;

   DisposableClass()
   {
      this.timer = new Timer(s => cb(s), s, 1000, 1000);
   }

   Init()
   {
       try
       {
           // Do some initialization here that is not done in ctor.
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
          // Log error.
          throw;
       }
       finally
       {
           // Is this correct?
           this.Dispose();
       }
   }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My question is whether the `finally` clause necessary (or should not have at all) in the above case, of for any non-constructor method when throwing an unhandled exception. Thanks.

EDIT:

In the answer, please address the issues depending on `Init()` being `public`,`protected`, `private` visibility levels.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question about visibility considerations. Updated the  question.

Comment: I think it may not be necessary... since calling `Dispose` should be done by the class consumer, and not by the class itself... I mean, consider the `using()` block, it compiles to a `try{} finally{}` block... so, even it the exception is thrown it will call `Dispose`

Comment: I mean, as an API consumer, I would not expect some instance to suddenly become disposed... I think that disposing itself should not be class's responsability

Comment: The class is not responsible for disposing own instance. If however you call `Init()` from constructor, then there will be no instance for someone to call `Dispose()`, then class is responsible for disposing the timer if it's created already (not necessarily via calling `Dispose()`, but via is also ok).

Comment: The problem with the code above for scenario when `Init` is a public method is inconsistent public contact behavior. Normally it's expected that your instance is in ready for consumption state right after its construction. If you're splitting initialization into different stages and break its atomicity by this, you're imposing potential consumption problems: possibility of half-initialized state, race conditions, etc. Doing all needed initialization stuff in constructor you mainly avoid these problems and shouldn't bother with extra disposal for an initialization failure.